# Jhipster: How to create a relationship using a field not the id

Tags: mysql, jhipster

I have 2 entities Country abd competions and i want to build a relationship betwenn them using the isoCode of the country, but when i generate the database(mySql) i find that the relation is based on the generated country_id.
What i'm missing?
Can i specify my own id and remove the generated id from the jdl file?

```
entity Country {
    isoCode String required
    .
    .
}

entity Competition {
    priority Integer,
    code String,
    name String
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Country to Competition{country(isoCode)}, 

   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JHipster only supports technical ids for relationships, if you want to use business ids you must code them manually, maybe have a look at Hibernate `@NaturalId`